# Stack around the variable 'product' was corrupted

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to multiply two matrices of different column lengths together, and the product matrix is correct, but it's been corrupted somehow.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "Matrix.h"

using std::cout, std::cin;

int main() {

    Matrix<> a({
        4, 5, 7, 3,
        2, 1, 2, 1,
        6, 2, 8, 9,
        9, 3, 6, 4
    });
    Matrix<4, 1> b({
        2,
        8,
        2,
        3
    });

    cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n';
    cout << a * b << '\n';
    
    cin.get();
}
```

```cpp
// Matrix.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template<unsigned int R = 4, unsigned int C = R, typename T = float>
struct Matrix {

    Matrix(T identity = 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            matrix[i][i] = identity;
    }

    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> indices) {
        int row = 0, column = 0;
        for (T index : indices) {
            matrix[row][column++] = index;
            if (column + 1 > C) {
                ++row;
                column = 0;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    T matrix[R][C] = {0};
public:

    T* operator[](unsigned int index) {
        return matrix[index];
    }

    const T* operator[](unsigned int index) const {
        return matrix[index];
    }

};

template<unsigned int R = 4, unsigned int C = R, typename T = float>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Matrix<R, C, T>& matrix) {

    for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; ++j) {
            stream << (j == 0 ? "[" : " ");
            stream << matrix[i][j];
            stream << (j + 1 == C ? "] \n" : "\0");
        }
    }

    return stream;
}

template<unsigned int M, unsigned int P, unsigned int N, typename T = float>
Matrix<M, N, T> operator*(const Matrix<M, P, T>& matrix, const Matrix<P, N, T>& other) {
    Matrix<M, N, T> product;

    std::cout << product << '\n';

    return product;
}
```

I made sure that that using an initializer list to construct a matrix produced the correct values.

The overloaded index operator also works as expected.

The function returns the correct matrix (4x4 • 4x1 = 4x1), and it logs the Matrix to the console.

How did it get corrupted?

[image]

Comment: Use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your code, then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) (with `watchpoint`s) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug it. Consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop if you don't have `gdb` and `valgrind`

Comment: I suspect the result of the multiplication is a temporary object which is destroyed and overwritten before it can be printed...

Comment: Hmmm, while the matrix b *looks* like a  <4,1> matrix, I think it is actually a <1,4> matrix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime error `Stack around the variable '*' is corrupted` pops up when you try to access memory which isn't allocated. This line `matrix[i][i] = identity;` poses the issue in the default constructor.

**Explanation:** 
In this matrix,

```cpp
Matrix<> a({
        4, 5, 7, 3,
        2, 1, 2, 1,
        6, 2, 8, 9,
        9, 3, 6, 4
});
```

The number of rows and columns are equal. Which means that accessing the matrix as `matrix[i][i]` wouldn't be an issue.

But in this matrix,

```cpp
Matrix<4, 1> b({
        2,
        8,
        2,
        3
});
```

The number or rows and columns doesn't match. At some point when using `matrix[i][i]` will result in something like this: `matrix[2][2]`.

This is what's happening under the hood. If we assign the relevant values to the operator.,we get something like this.

```cpp
Matrix<4, 1, T> operator*(const Matrix<4, 4, int>& matrix, const Matrix<4, 1, int>& other) {
    Matrix<4, 1, T> product;

    std::cout << product << '\n';

    return product;
}
```

Now in the default constructor, the `for loop` will write to a variable location which isn't allocated. This is the reason to the stack corruption.

Comment: I see, so that's the issue. Is there some kind of check I can do that make make sure I can write into the memory? My first solution would be making sure the number of Rows are equal to the number of Columns.

Comment: If your matrix needs to have the same number of rows and columns, you can do a static assert: `static_assert(R == C, "Number Rows must be equal to the number of Columns!")`. If not use 2 nested for loops to assign values (one for rows and the other for columns).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is constructor:

```cpp
    Matrix(T identity = 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            matrix[i][i] = identity;
    }
```

Note what it does in case `R = 4`  and `C = 1`.

Address sanitizer [finds this](https://godbolt.org/z/j8TT9a) without problems.

Fixed version:

```cpp
    Matrix(T identity = 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < std::min(R, C); ++i)
            matrix[i][i] = identity;
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ns1q5c